# Python Pandas Replacing column names

Tags: python, pandas, renaming

I am using pandas and python to process multiple files with different column names for columns with the same data.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', index_col=0)

cols= dataset.columns
```

I have the different possible column titles in a list.

```
AddressCol=['sAddress','address','Adrs', 'cAddress']
```

Is there a way to normalize all the possible column names to "Address" in pandas so I use the script on different files?

Without pandas I would use something like a double for loop to go through the list of column names and possible column names and a if statement to extract out the whole array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) DataFrame method:

```
dataset.rename(columns={typo: 'Address' for typo in AddressCol}, inplace=True)
```